# rpm -K showing signed, but not by correct key

Tags: rpm, gnupg, yocto

I'm building a project based in the yocto openembedded environment. I have set up gpg signing using the sign_rpm recipe.

I then plan to upload the rpms for use with Smart.

Having set up the correct public keys on the development board, I can verify that the rpms generated by the build are signed correctly (using rpm -K.) I can also verify that the files generated before this do not pass the verification.

The problem: When my co-worker (who has neither the changes to recipes to generate signed files nor the private key) generates a build and I pull it  down through Smart, the files appear as signed.

Files I have signed report:

(sha1) dsa sha1 md5 OK

Files he has uploaded (or copied directly to me) report the same.

Since I am gpg signing the files (or at least I believe I am) should I be seeing gpg in the output of the rpm -K command?

And to call this out once more, the rpm I copied over before I built the signed rpms shows correctly that it's unsigned:

RSA sha1 md5 NOT_OK

Hopefully I've explained this well enough someone can see why: A - files that shouldn't be signed pass the signing check, and B - why older rpms fail the check as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RPM --checksig used "gpg" and "pgp" for header+payload signatures which are no longer used in RPM5.

The algorithm names "rsa" and "dsa" and "ecdsa" are displayed for header-only signatures.

Comment: What would I do to check header and payload in RPM5? Or would you say it looks like I'm not correctly signing with gpg?

Comment: You would have to re-add (or mostly re-enable) the header+payload signatures in RPM5. The header+payload signature was phased out back in 2008, largely because the payload does not exist (and the signature cannot be verified) after the *.rpm is installed. The header-only signature can be verified on installed packages.

Comment: I went with externally signing the RPMs, drops a hitch in the Smart update process and not as elegant as I'd like, but seems to be the best way to get it done.